# Android: Checking for sqlite table existence always returns true

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have this method which checks whether a table exists in that database or not.However it always returns true.

```
public boolean checkDomainTableExists(String domain){

        if (database==null||!database.isOpen()){
            database=dBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        if (!database.isReadOnly()){
            database.close();
            database=dBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }

        try{
            cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = ? AND name = ?", new String[] {"table", tableName});

        }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("exception",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        if (cursor!=null){
            if (cursor.getCount()>0){
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

While I am debugging, I see the `cursor` count as -1 by the time it reaches to  `if (cursor.getCount()>0){` and cursor count become 1 when I step over the `breakpoint` resulting in method return `true`.

Whatever the tablename I give, this method always return true.

Here are the screenshots for debug console:
[image]

At this point the cursor count is -1, so I believe it shouldn't get into the loop, but it does and the count goes to 1.

Edit: I also tried the following query:

```
database.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '" + tableName + "'", null);
```

Even in this case, getCount is 1 always.

and

```
try{
        cursor=database.query(tableName,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        tableExists=true;
    }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("exception",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Here the bool tableExists is always false.

[image]

Where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` will always return one entry. Rather than looking at `getCount()`, move to the 0th position and call `getInt(0)` to retrieve the value generated by `SELECT COUNT(*)`. There, you are looking for 0 or 1, presumably.

Comment: When I do cursor.getInt(0), I get android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: when u say move cursor to 0th postion, do you mean to call cursor.moveToFirst() ?

Comment: getCount returns 1, and getPosition returns -1. I am unable to use getInt(0) @CommonsWare